# When is clean_data populated in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a model_formset, created with can_delete=True and added the corresponding form.DELETE checkboxes to the template.
When I get a POST request, I try to save the forms:

```
if formset.is_valid():
    formset.save()
```

However, in the is_valid method, django determines the deleted forms souldn't be deleted and, of course, it doesn't validate.

I have checked the source code and it seems that 'DELETED' isn't getting into clean_data.
Django performs this check:

```
def _should_delete_form(self, form):
    return form.cleaned_data.get(DELETION_FIELD_NAME, False)
```

I checked the request.POST dictionary and the check is there, meaning it should be in the  clean_data dict.

When is this dict populated so I can further track the issue? I don't seem to find it and suspect it has to do with some metaclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to go a bit into the source code for this:

First,  [`is_valid` is defined as](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L157)

```
def is_valid(self):
    """
    Returns True if the form has no errors. Otherwise, False. If errors are
    being ignored, returns False.
    """
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
```

and [`self.errors` is a `property`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L150)

```
@property
def errors(self):
    "Returns an ErrorDict for the data provided for the form"
    if self._errors is None:
        self.full_clean()
    return self._errors
```

which calls [`self.full_clean()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L351). Now this method has

```
self._clean_fields()
self._clean_form()
self._post_clean()
```

Which populate the `cleaned_data` and do the necessary validation/processing.

Comment: However, it iterates over its fields to populate clean_data. This means, the DELETE field must be manually added to the form in order for this to work. I added a DELETE hidden input to my base forms